# How to mock Ruby Module functions?

Tags: ruby, module, rspec, mocking

How can I mock module functions of a self-written module inside my project?

Given the module and function

```ruby
module ModuleA::ModuleB
  def self.my_function( arg )
  end
end
```

which is called like

```ruby
ModuleA::ModuleB::my_function( with_args )
```

How should I mock it when it's used inside a function I'm writing specs for?

---

Doubling it (`obj = double("ModuleA::ModuleB")`) makes no sense for me as the function is called on the module and not on an object.

I've tried stubbing it (`ModuleA::ModuleB.stub(:my_function).with(arg).and_return(something)`). Obviously, it did not work. `stub` is not defined there.

Then I've tried it with `should_receive`. Again `NoMethodError`.

What is the preferred way of mocking a module and it's functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the module you describe in your question

```
module ModuleA ; end

module ModuleA::ModuleB
  def self.my_function( arg )
  end
end
```

and the function under test, which calls the module function

```
def foo(arg)
  ModuleA::ModuleB.my_function(arg)
end
```

then you can test that `foo` calls `myfunction` like this:

```
describe :foo do
  it "should delegate to myfunction" do
    arg = mock 'arg'
    result = mock 'result'
    ModuleA::ModuleB.should_receive(:my_function).with(arg).and_return(result)
    foo(arg).should == result
  end
end
```

Comment: That's basically, what I tried. Thanks for the wrap-up. My problem however was, that I put that `should_receive` in an `before :all` block. Obviously that does not work. How stupid of me.

Comment: @Torbjoern, Oh yeah.  Been there.  Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: In current rspec (3.6) it gives "Using `should_receive` from rspec-mocks' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead."

Answer (score 1):

For rspec 3.6 see [How to mock class method in RSpec expect syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888068/how-to-mock-class-method-in-rspec-expect-syntax)

To avoid link-only-answer, here is copy of answer by Andrey Deineko:

```
allow(Module)
  .to receive(:profile)
  .with("token")
  .and_return({"name" => "Hello", "id" => "14314141", "email" => "hello@me.com"})
```