# How to mock class method in RSpec expect syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a confusion about how to mock a class method using new `expect` syntax.
This works:

```
Facebook
  .should_receive(:profile)
  .with("token")
  .and_return({"name" => "Hello", "id" => "14314141", "email" => "hello@me.com"})
```

and this doesn't:

```
facebook = double("Facebook")
allow(facebook).to receive(:profile).with("token").and_return({"name" => "Hello", "id" => "14314141", "email" => "hello@me.com"})
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: `allow(Facebook).to receive(:profile).with("token").and_return({"name" => "Hello", "id" => "14314141", "email" => "hello@me.com"})` should work

Comment: Amazing, that worked like a charm. The docs are very difficult.

Comment: right, mocking and stubbing isn't the easiest topic..

Comment: Hint: there are no class methods in Ruby. Only instance methods. The question is: in which class are they defined and on which instance are they called? If you can answer that question, then you know what to do, since you already know how to mock instance methods, and there are no class methods, only instance methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you want to do (no need for `double`):

```
allow(Facebook)
  .to receive(:profile)
  .with("token")
  .and_return({"name" => "Hello", "id" => "14314141", "email" => "hello@me.com"})
```